# Try to Separate String in C read from a txt

Tags: c

Make the following code to be able to separate the string:

> CristinaRodriguezRiveraComputacion210302414

but I want to know how much of the code I have to modify or what I can modify of the code so that I can separate this:

> CristinaRodriguezRiveraComputacion210302414RamiroSilvaPerezIndustrial217890453PatriciaDuranSanchezCivil215643525RaulColinGranadosComputacion215678342

the code correctly separates the first string but I would like to implement the pertinent modifications :)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <string.h> 
 
 
int complete_lowercase(char dinamic[], int longdinamico, char destiny[], int ini) { 
   int fin = ini + 1; 
   while (islower(dinamic[fin])) { 
      ++fin; 
   } 
   memcpy(destiny, &dinamic[ini], fin - ini); 
   return fin; 
} 
 
void separate_data(char dinamic[], int longdinamic, char name[], char father[], char mother[], char degree[], char id[]) { 
   int ini_father = complete_lowercase(dinamic, longdinamic, name, 0); 
   int ini_mother = complete_lowercase(dinamic, longdinamic, father, ini_father); 
   int ini_degree = complete_lowercase(dinamic, longdinamic, mother, ini_mother); 
   int ini_id = complete_lowercase(dinamic, longdinamic, degree, ini_degree); 
   memcpy(id, &dinamic[ini_id], longdinamic - ini_id); 
} 
 
int main(){ 
    FILE*  ent = fopen("DatosEntrada.txt","r"); 
    FILE*  sal = fopen("SalidaBytes.txt","a"); 
 
    if(ent != NULL){ 
        char name[15]; 
        char father[15]; 
        char mother[15]; 
        char degree[15]; 
        char id[15]; 
 
        memset(name, ' ', sizeof(name)); 
        memset(father, ' ', sizeof(father)); 
        memset(mother, ' ', sizeof(mother)); 
        memset(degree, ' ', sizeof(degree)); 
        memset(id, ' ', sizeof(id)); 
 
        fseek(ent, 0, SEEK_END); //file length 
        int longarch = ftell(ent); 
        rewind(ent);  //go back to the start 
 
        char dinamic[longarch+1]; 
        fscanf(ent,"%s",&dinamic); 
 
        separate_data(dinamic, longarch+1, name, father, mother, degree, id); 
 
        fwrite(name, sizeof(char), 15, sal); 
        fwrite(father, sizeof(char), 15, sal); 
        fwrite(mother, sizeof(char), 15, sal); 
        fwrite(degree, sizeof(char), 15, sal); 
        fwrite(id, sizeof(char), 15, sal); 
 
        printf("\nCreated File\n"); 
        fclose(ent); 
        fclose(sal); 
 
    }else{ 
 
       fprintf(stdout, "ERROR: %s", strerror(errno)); 
    } 
 
}
```

Comment: What's the question?  Complete my code is not a question.  It's relatively straight forward strpbrk(s, UPPER NUMBER).  If the result is a number then you need to search only for upper case next, otherwise it's the same pattern.  #define UPPER "A...Z" and NUMBER="0...9" (write those out).

Comment: @AllanWind I wasn't asking to complete my code :( , I was just asking for some recommendation on what to do, thanks for the proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the current character is a number then search for the next upper case letter, otherwise search for either a number or upper case.  This is transition between the current and next word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define UPPER "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
#define NUMBER "0123456789"

int main() {
    const char *s = "CristinaRodriguezRiveraComputacion210302414RamiroSilvaPerezIndustrial217890453PatriciaDuranSanchezCivil215643525RaulColinGranadosComputacion215678342";
    for(;;) {
        const char *pattern = strchr(NUMBER, *s) ? UPPER : UPPER NUMBER;
        const char *s2 = strpbrk(s + 1, pattern);
        if(!s2) {
            printf("%s\n", s);
            break;
        }
        printf("%.*s\n", s2 - s, s);
        s = s2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and it would generate the following output:

```
Cristina
Rodriguez
Rivera
Computacion
210302414
Ramiro
Silva
Perez
Industrial
217890453
Patricia
Duran
Sanchez
Civil
215643525
Raul
Colin
Granados
Computacion
215678342
```

Answer (score 1):

A character could be read from the input file and printed to the output file.
Based on upper case and digits, spaces and newlines can be printed to the output file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ( void) {
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t fieldcount = 0;
    FILE*  ent = NULL;
    FILE*  sal = NULL;

    if ( NULL == ( ent = fopen ( "DatosEntrada.txt","r"))) {
        perror ( "DatosEntrada.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    if ( NULL == ( sal = fopen ( "SalidaBytes.txt","w"))) {
        fclose ( ent);
        perror ( "SalidaBytes.txt");
        return 2;
    }

    int in = 0;
    while ( EOF != ( in = fgetc ( ent))) {
        if ( isupper ( (unsigned char)in)) {
            ++fieldcount;
            if ( 1 < fieldcount && 5 > fieldcount) {
                for ( int space = len; space < 15; ++space) {
                    fputc ( ' ', sal);
                }
            }
            len = 0;
            if ( 6 == fieldcount) {
                fputc ( '\n', sal);
                fieldcount = 1;
            }
            fputc ( in, sal);
            continue;
        }
        if ( 4 == fieldcount && len && isdigit ( (unsigned char)in)) {
            ++fieldcount;
            for ( int space = len; space < 15; ++space) {
                fputc ( ' ', sal);
            }
            len = 0;
            fputc ( in, sal);
            continue;
        }
        if ( 15 > len) {
            fputc ( in, sal);
        }
        ++len;
    }

    fclose ( ent);
    fclose ( sal);
    return 0;
}
```

The output file is:

```
Cristina        Rodriguez       Rivera          Computacion     210302414
Ramiro          Silva           Perez           Industrial      217890453
Patricia        Duran           Sanchez         Civil           215643525
Raul            Colin           Granados        Computacion     215678342
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this problem. @AllanWard has a great approach using `string.h` functions and a couple of constants. Another approach is to use the macros `isupper()`, `islower()` and `isdigit()` provided in `ctype.h`. There you can trivially just catch each uppercase letter or each digit preceded by a lowercase letter for separating the words.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {
  
  const char *s = "CristinaRodriguezRiveraComputacion210302414RamiroSilvaPer"
                  "ezIndustrial217890453PatriciaDuranSanchezCivil21564"
                  "3525RaulColinGranadosComputacion215678342";
                  
  for (const char *p = s; ; p++) {
    if (!*p || isupper(*p) || (isdigit(*p) && islower(*(p-1)))) {
      if (p > s) {
        putchar ('\n');
      }
      if (!*p) {
        break;
      }
    }
    putchar (*p);
  }
}
```

(**note:** a separate pointer `p` was used to preserve `s` (in case you needed it later), but if you were doing the separation in a function you can simply walk-down `s` (the pointer passed as a parameter) without using a separate pointer)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sepupperdigit
Cristina
Rodriguez
Rivera
Computacion
210302414
Ramiro
Silva
Perez
Industrial
217890453
Patricia
Duran
Sanchez
Civil
215643525
Raul
Colin
Granados
Computacion
215678342
```

**Separating Into 15-Character Fields**

If you want your output separated into lines of words with a field-width of 15-characters each, then you simply need to rearrange your tests and keep a counter. The counter is used to determine how many spaces to write after each word in the field.

Adding a counter and rearranging your tests you can do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define FLDWIDTH 15

int main (void) {
  
  const char *s = "CristinaRodriguezRiveraComputacion210302414RamiroSilvaPer"
                  "ezIndustrial217890453PatriciaDuranSanchezCivil21564"
                  "3525RaulColinGranadosComputacion215678342";
  int n = 0;
  
  for (const char *p = s; ; p++, n++) {
    if (!*p || (isupper(*p) && isdigit(*(p-1)))) {
      putchar ('\n');
      if (!*p) {
        break;
      }
      n = 0;
    }
    else if (isupper(*p) || (isdigit(*p) && islower(*(p-1)))) {
      if (p > s) {
        int spaces = FLDWIDTH - n;
        while (spaces--) {
          putchar (' ');
        }
        n = 0;
      }
    }
    putchar (*p);
  }
}
```

(**note:** you can simply use `fputc()` instead of `putchar()` to write the output to a file. Also note as @AllanWard points out, this fits for this data but doesn't protect against checking one before the start if the string starts with digits. Originally, the `p > s` condition was placed in the conditional, e.g. `else if (isupper(*p) || (p > s && (isdigit(*p) && islower(*(p-1)))))`, which will handle the generic case, but was moved below for readability and the data in this problem.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sepupperdigit2
Cristina       Rodriguez      Rivera         Computacion    210302414
Ramiro         Silva          Perez          Industrial     217890453
Patricia       Duran          Sanchez        Civil          215643525
Raul           Colin          Granados       Computacion    215678342
```

Comment: Wouldn't `*(p-1)` underflow if the first word consist of digits?  I guess it's a phone number so maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AllanWind - yes, generically it would. I originally had `p > s` as a condition in that series of conditionals, but for the given input it made it more difficult to read, so I broke it out and moved it to its own block. Good catch. In each case doing, e.g.  `else if (isupper(*p) || (p > s && (isdigit(*p) && islower(*(p-1)))))` protects against that case -- but it was a bit messy.